# How do I change the value of a text box from another class file?

Tags: text, textbox

I have a windows form up. In my `Form1` class, I can set `txtBox.Text="text"` and it would change and update it.

I have another class, let's call it foo.

How would I in the foo class be able to change `txtBox.Text` from the foo class?

For example:

```
 Class Form1: Form
{
txtBox.Text="0230104";
}

//In a different class file
Class foo
{
txtBox.Text="0";
}
```

How would I be able to change the text box with text from another class other than `Form1`?

Comment: What language are you using?  c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to Form1:

```
  public string TxtBoxText { 
    get { return txtBox.Text; }
    set { txtBox.Text = value;}
  }
```

Comment: How would I add this?

Comment: Add it to the Form1.cs file somewhere within the class.